# LM386 noise when using 5v power supply

Tags: charger, 5v, lm386, guitar-pedal

I'm using LM386 with my guitar and currently I power it with 9v battery but now I want to switch to 5v power supply because I don't want to use a battery.

I want to use a 5v usb wall charger + sparkfun usb mini-b breakout but it doesn't work, it haves a lot of noise/static.
If I use a 7805 with the 9v battery it works flawlessly.

What's wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you grounded the LM's ground pin?

Comment: Your PS stinks. Use a 9V PSU instead, or a 6V PSU and a LDO regulator.

Comment: Read the datasheet. Not all 386 variants can tolerate running at 5V, and you're not going to get much out of it at 5V either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely cause is noise from the power supply.

5V USB power supplies assume that they don't have to clean up the output from the switching power supply, since you are going to use it to charge a device - the device's charging circuit doesn't care about noise, and the device itself runs off of the battery.

By the time the current from the charger reaches any audio stages, it has been through the charge regulator, various amounts of filtering, and the battery itself (which can swallow some/all of the noise.)

But, you are using it to power the amplifier directly so you get the full effect of the switching noise.

[This guy ran some tests.](http://budgetlightforum.com/node/18731)

As you can see by the oscilloscope pictures, there's a lot of noise.
Like this:
[image]

There's better ones and worse ones, but yeah, noise from a USB charger is to be expected.

You'll need to do some filtering of your 5V and GND lines if you want to use that charger.

Easiest is probably getting hold of a 9Volt charger and using a 5Volt linear regulator. You don't need an LDO (Low DropOut) regulator, just a garden variety linear regulator like the 7805 you mentioned.

Actually, you could probably run the amp straight off of the 9V power supply if it is clean.  If not, use your 7805.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with this one. An apple iPhone charger is way better than the cheap ones you get from shady stores. See here: http://www.righto.com/2012/10/a-dozen-usb-chargers-in-lab-apple-is.html

Comment: Actually, the guy I linked to did test an Apple charger, and it was by far the best (noise wise.)

Comment: Well I guess the link I gave has prettier graphs :P (for my tastes, that is. Dark background with light elements)

Comment: I have a 10μF+100pF on the power rail but nothing changes. I guess i will have to buy a 9v power supply

Comment: @PandaLion98:  :)

Comment: @lorigio 10uf is way too low. The ESR of small electrolytes usually is on high side. You may need +100μf, and may be a choke or 1Ohm resistor in series before the caps.